# java8 how to collection data and add as the properties of object then to a List

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

Before java8 we write code like this:

```
    List<ResultDTO> resources = Lists.newArrayList();        

    List<Product> productList = details.getProducts();
    for (Product product : productList) {
        ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
        result.setName(product.getName);
        result.setNumber(product.getNumber);

        resources.add(resourceDetail);
    }
```

And Java8 I write like this:

```
List<ResultDTO> resources = Lists.newArrayList();
details.getProducts.stream().forEach( product -> {
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setName(product.getName);
    result.setNumber(product.getNumber);

    resources.add(resourceDetail);
} );
```

I wonder if there are some tips when we traversing stream create ResultDTO objects set its properties and then to a list ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a list and modifying it inside the stream operations is an anti-pattern. You should let the stream create the list for you:

```
List<ResultDTO> resources = 
    details.getProducts()
           .stream()
           .map(this::createResultDTO)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where the createResultDTO method would create a ResultDTO from a Product (you can of course inline its code inside map, but it's much less readable).

Comment: I would personally probably add a static factory method on `ProductResultDTO` called `fromProduct` so you can write `map(ProductResultDTO::fromProduct)`

Answer (score 2):

As JB mentioned, you would want to create list from the stream.

```
List<ResultDTO> resources = details.getProducts()
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(this::createResultDTO)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And here would be the `createResultDTO` method.

```
public ResultDTO createResultDTO(Product p){
    ResultDTO result = new ResultDTO();
    result.setName(p.getName);
    result.setNumber(p.getNumber);
    return result;
}
```

You can put this method in the same class and use

`.map(this::createResultDTO)`

or in a different class called `ProductResultDTO` and use the following:

`.map(ProductResultDTO::createResultDTO)`